# How to use more than two "WHERE" clause? MYSQL ERROR

Tags: php, mysql, select

I am using it to do with PHP.

ERROR:-

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1`

**EDIT 1:**

```
$SQLQUERY = sprintf("SELECT pd_serial FROM product_details WHERE pd_model_type=%s AND pd_model_name=%s AND pd_model_version=%s AND pd_product_group=%s LIMIT 1",
GetSQLValueString($modeltype, "text"),
GetSQLValueString($modelname, "text"),
GetSQLValueString($modelversion, "text"),
GetSQLValueString($modelgroup, "text"));
$QUERYEXEC =  mysql_query($SQLQUERY, $dacreint) or die("OOPS! Please try again.");

while ($QUERYFETCH = mysql_fetch_array($QUERYEXEC))
{
    $pdserial = $QUERYFETCH['pd_serial'];
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
while ($QUERYFETCH = mysql_fetch_array($QUERYEXEC))
{
    $pdserial = $QUERYFETCH['pd_serial'];
}
$SQLQUERY = sprintf("SELECT product_serial_no FROM products WHERE product_serial_no = '$product_serial_no'");
$TCcount_QE = mysql_query($SQLQUERY, $dacreint) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: what error code is displaying?

Comment: Is the `WHERE` clause is ok??

Comment: Please add in the PHP code you're using with this query (we shouldn't have to ask for this).

Comment: where clause is ok here. Problem is in the input value(s) I believe

Comment: @halfer please reconsider, i have edit my question

Comment: @AbhilashShukla - great edit, thanks; downvote reverted.

Comment: @halfer Thanks... it actually pains :|

Comment: Not sure why you removed the definition for `GetSQLValueString()` from your question, as that is very relevant. Couple of things: looks like you have a potential SQL injection vulnerability for string columns in that method (well, if you pass in tainted values from the user). Also, you would benefit from switching to PDO MySQL and using parameter binding. If you do the latter, that will fix the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put strings within single quotes. And make sure you have escaped those string values using `mysql_real_escape_string()` or similar function

```
SELECT pd_serial FROM product_details WHERE (pd_model_type='%s' AND pd_model_name='%s') AND (pd_model_version='%s' AND pd_model_group='%s') LIMIT 1
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
            while ($QUERYFETCH = mysql_fetch_array($QUERYEXEC))
            {
                $pdserial = $QUERYFETCH['pd_serial'];
            }
    // let's comment out the following line
        //    $SQLQUERY = sprintf("SELECT product_serial_no FROM products WHERE product_serial_no = '$product_serial_no'");
// and modifying it as:
            $SQLQUERY = sprintf("SELECT product_serial_no FROM products WHERE product_serial_no = %s", GetSQLValueString($product_serial_no, "text"));
            $TCcount_QE = mysql_query($SQLQUERY, $dacreint) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: I have already defined a function to handle `mysql_real_escape_string()` so i am done with it..

Comment: what about the single quotes? e.g: `pd_model_type='%s'`

Comment: Ok. I can see that. But, are you sure the error is produce from this particular query? I cannot see here you calling `mysql_error()` or similar functions! May be the error could be from different query

Comment: Can you modify the line to `$SQLQUERY = sprintf("SELECT product_serial_no FROM products WHERE product_serial_no = '%s'", $product_serial_no);` ?

Comment: Hey thanks for the help... but actually i have one more syntax where i have `VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s` so it has to be like `VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)`... was a blunder mistake... Still thanks a lot for the help...

Answer (score 0):

Could you please add the "rendered" query? Are your parameters, which should be set in "%s" set in quotes?

by the way: you don't have to set the parentheses inside a completely "AND"-linked WHERE-statement.

Comment: ok so it has to be something like this:- `WHERE pd_model_type=%s AND pd_model_name=%s AND pd_model_version=%s AND pd_model_group=%s`

Comment: right. Whats your command to fill your sql-query? Could you send a concrete query, how it is generated by your php?

PS: it might help you, to write your SQL-Queries along mutliple lines, to get a better idea **where** to debug in your query. "line 1" as buggy position isn't quite helpful yet. ;)

Be sure to set Strings with quotes. e.g.:

`WHERE pd_model_type = 'ps3' AND pd_model_name = 'slim' AND pd_model_version= '2.0b' AND pd_model_group = 'entertainment'`

Comment: @AbhilashShukla - no, that's not the 'rendered' query. The rendered query is what it looks like after you've bound/replaced the parameter values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct query

```
SELECT pd_serial FROM product_details WHERE pd_model_type=%s AND pd_model_name=%s AND pd_model_version=%s AND pd_model_group=%s LIMIT 1
```

Edited

```
SELECT pd_serial FROM product_details WHERE pd_model_type like '%s' AND pd_model_name like '%s' AND pd_model_version like '%s' AND pd_model_group like '%s' LIMIT 1
```

Sorry i forgot to enclose like condition in brackets and i was missing like because we are using wild card here

Comment: with or without brackets, both are same

Comment: That's the same as the OP's query, isn't it?